# $f \colon G_1 \to G_2$ group homomorphism, then $G_1 / N_1 \cong G_2 / N_2$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I'm stuck on a question regarding group theory, related to the isomorphism theorems. I am given a group homomorphism $f \colon G_1 \to G_2$, and $N_2$ a normal subgroup of $G_2$. I have proven that the pre-image $N_1 := f^{-1}(N_2)$ is a normal subgroup of $G_1$. Now, if we assume $f$ is surjective, I need to prove that $G_1 / N_1 \cong G_2 / N_2$.

I have already thought of using the first isomorphism theorem, but this has only lead to the conclusion that $G_1 / N_1 \cong G_2$, because $N_1$ is a normal subgroup and thus a kernel, and $f$ is surjective. Other than that, I have thought of using the canonical homomorphism $\varphi \colon G_2 \to G_2/N_2$. I suppose I could show the composition $\varphi \circ f$ is a bijection, but I'm not sure about how to prove this or whether this is the right direction for the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, observe that
\begin{align*}
\varphi : G_1 &\to G_2/N_2 \\
g_1 &\mapsto f(g_1)+N_2
\end{align*}

is a surjective group homomorphism.

Now, the identity of $G_2/N_2$ is $N_2$, and the inverse image of it is $N_1$.

So, the Kernel of the map $\varphi$ is $N_1$.

By $1$st isomorphism theorem, the result follows.

Comment: Why is $N_2$ the identity in $G_2/N_2$?

Comment: Because, the elements of $G_2/N_2$ are $a+N_2, b+N_2, c+N_2, \dots$. We have $(a+N_2)\cdot N_2 = a+N_2$. Also, $(b+N_2) \cdot N_2 = b+N_2$. So $N_2$ is something like a "$1$". Multiplying by it doesn't affect the result.

Comment: Right, makes sense. Thanks, helpful answer!

Comment: @Jason Loosely, when you mod out by $N_2$, it is set to $e$.  Or, by the definition of the quotient...

Comment: @ThePortakal : Why do you mix additive and multiplicative notation ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\pi_i : G_i \rightarrow G_i / N_i$ be the two projection maps. Then if $\tilde{f} := \pi \circ f$, we have that $\tilde{f}$ is surjective, and that $ker\left(\tilde{f}\right) = N_1$. Then, by the isomorphism theorem, there is a map $\widehat{f} : G_1 / N_1 \rightarrow G_2 / N_2$ such that $\widehat{f} = \tilde{f} \circ \pi_1$. $\widehat{f}$ is injective by the theorem of isomorphism, and surjective because $\tilde{f}$ is.

Comment: I was too slow...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the commutative diagram:
\begin{alignat}{2}
G_1&\twoheadrightarrow&~& G_1/N_1\\
\downarrow~&&&\enspace\,\downarrow \\
G_2&\twoheadrightarrow&& G_2/N_2
\end{alignat}
The lower  way from $G_1$ to $G_2/N_2$  is surjective by hypothesis, so the upper way: $G_1 \to G_1/N_1 \to G_2/N_2$ is surjective, hence the second map is surjective.